# How do I set a symbolic breakpoint on _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uikit

I'm using Xcode 4.3.2 with lldb as my debugger.

I have inherited a project that contains code that is calling UIKit from secondary threads, as shown by these log messages:

> 2012-05-02 21:48:14.603 Appname Dev[77594:16e0f] void
>   _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool), 0x8d5f810: Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit
>   should not be called from a secondary thread.

I have cleaned up most of the code that was making UIKit calls from secondary threads, but I am still occasionally seeing this message in the logs. The app is not crashing, so it's difficult to pinpoint where the problem lies.

I'd like to set a breakpoint on `_WebThreadLockFromAnyThread`, but when I try to set a symbolic breakpoint using:

```
b _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread
```

the debugger tells me:

> breakpoint set --name '_WebThreadLockFromAnyThread' Breakpoint
>   created: 12: name = '_WebThreadLockFromAnyThread', locations = 0
>   (pending) WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual
>   locations.

I've also tried creating the symbolic breakpoint using the UI in the breakpoint navigator, but I'm not sure what to enter for the module. When I leave the module blank, the breakpoint is created but it's still not breaking when the log message appears in the debug console.

Can anyone tell me how I can go about adding a breakpoint on `_WebThreadLockFromAnyThread`, and also how I would determine what the defining module is for this symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just leave out the underscore.  b WebThreadLockFromAnyThread works for me in both lldb and gdb.  Now, this is Xcode 4.6, so if you're stuck on the older version I suppose it's possible that there's an issue in that version not present in 4.6.

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much! I ended up using the following similar command that also sets a condition such that it only breaks if the function is called outside of the main thread: `break set -n WebThreadLockFromAnyThread -c '!(BOOL)[NSThread isMainThread]'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try use nm command or class-dump tool to locate the module.

Comment: I tried using nm on the executable that Xcode produced when I built my app, but the symbol is not located in it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there are no symbols you need because xcode by default produces a "release" build which if I am correct strips the symbols making the exec file much smaller. I am not sure how at the moment but you need to find the option to switch to "debug" build which will guarantee to have all those lovely symbols waiting for your analysis.

Comment: I'm working with a build that has "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" set to "No".