# what does this log means when i do nslog

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
2020-05-14 23:41:56.342599+0530 appName[3552:186526] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.
```

just want to know what this means [3552:186526].

Comment: You can change UI stuff only in main thread. What are you doing exactly?

Comment: i am working on sdk but there are 1000 of queue i can't find where it is crashing due to which queue does this mean some line number [3552:186526]  ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053475/detect-ui-actions-outside-of-main-thread : Manually add a breakpoint, or use the Main Thread Checker in the building/running options...

Comment: thank really for the help. but when i use this it take me to some random page of Xcode not targeting my file or my code stuck on this from 5 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're specifically asking what the `[3552:186526]` part of the message means. The number to the left of the colon (3552, in this case) is the process ID of that specific instance of your app. If you run it again, it would generally log a different number.

The number to the right of the color (186526) is a thread identifier for the thread which caused the problem. However, it's mostly useless because it's hard to correlate that to the thread IDs presented by the debugger. Also, again, it would be different for every run of the app.

Comment: u have any best way to find that thread which is causing issue i mean the queue which is making app crash?

Comment: As Larme suggested in comments, the Main Thread Checker should do this for you. If it's identifying Apple code rather than your own, you probably need to just look at the stack trace for the thread in the Debug navigator sidebar. Find a frame of yours, select it, and you should see your code.